# 2 activities 1 button

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

I have MainActivity with button and I want to move between 2 other activities from MainActivity with 1 button. I tried to use intent.getExtra with if but it didn't work or I used it wrong. Can you help with it?

Firstchoose.kt

```
package anti.stress.antistress

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_firstchoose.*

class Firstchoose : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_firstchoose)

        val one = findViewById<Button>(R.id.one)
        one.setOnClickListener {
            val one = Intent(this, Fiveways::class.java).putExtra("f",1)
            //one.putExtra("c",1)
            startActivity(one)

        eight.setOnClickListener {
            val eight = Intent(this, Fiveways::class.java).putExtra("ei",8)
            //eight.putExtra("c",8)
            startActivity(eight)
        }
    }
}
```

Fiveways.kt is

```
package anti.stress.antistress

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_fiveways.*

class Fiveways : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fiveways)

        angry2.setOnClickListener{
            val angry = Intent(this, Advice::class.java)
            startActivity(angry)
        }
        alone4.setOnClickListener{
            val alone = Intent(this, Adviceofv::class.java)
            startActivity(alone)
        }
        sad3.setOnClickListener {
            val sad = Intent(this, Adviceoth::class.java)
            startActivity(sad)
        }
        useless3.setOnClickListener {
            val useless = Intent(this, Adviceof::class.java)
            startActivity(useless)
        }
        afraid2.setOnClickListener {
            val afraid = Intent(this, Adviceot::class.java)
            startActivity(afraid)
        }
    }
}
```

Fiveways.kt is open by both buttons (one and eight) but if I clicked on FirstchooseActivity button`one` then button`angry2` will open AdviceActivity, if I clicked on FirstchooseActivity button `eight` then but button`angry2` must open OtherAdviceActivity. Can somebody help with it? Maybe I don't need `intent.putExtra`?

Comment: What is the purpose of the 1 button? if you want to you need to open activity-based on the button string from a button or you can use 2 buttons

Comment: I'm need to open OneActivity and TwoActivity only with using one button

Comment: Check out my answer hope its helps

Comment: I updated my quesiton. Check it if you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do is first write the condition and pass Intent in it accordingly like, first when if(your condition1) then pass Intent for whatever activity you wanted to open and then into else part or into else if condition add another Intent for whatever another activity you want to open.

```
if(your condition1){
  angry2.setOnClickListener{
        val angry = Intent(this, Advice::class1.java)
        startActivity(angry)
    }
else if(your condition2){
 angry2.setOnClickListener{
        val angry = Intent(this, Advice::class2.java)
        startActivity(angry)
    }
```

}

Hope so it will help you.

Comment: when I write `val intent = Intent(this, OneActivity::class.java) if (intent.getIntExtra("name", value) startActivity(intent) else val secondintent = Intent(this, OtherActivity::class.java) startActivity(secondintent)` it doesn't work. Last it open OtherActivity in both results

Comment: try my answer because I seem that may be you have syntactical error like you applying condition at wrong place

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your need Extra for that.In your main activity check the value of your variable before the intent.

```
if(value == 1){
      angry2.setOnClickListener{
            val angry = Intent(this, Advice::class1.java)
            startActivity(angry)
        }
  else if(value == 2){
     angry2.setOnClickListener{
            val angry = Intent(this, Advice::class2.java)
            startActivity(angry)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the intent from main activity like

```
  val value= getIntent().getIntExtra("f")
  angry2.setOnClickListener{
        if (value == 1) {
            val angry = Intent(this, First::class.java)
        startActivity(angry)
        }else{
        val angry = Intent(this, Advice::class.java)
        startActivity(angry)  
      }

    }
```

Comment: It compile but open simple activity :( `override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fiveways)

        val value = getIntent().getIntExtra("f", 1)
        angry2.setOnClickListener{
            if (value == 1) {
            val angry = Intent(this, Advice::class.java)
            startActivity(angry) }
            else {
                val other = Intent(this, Adviceeio::class.java)
                startActivity(other)
            }
        }`